# Saxon produces empty XML from Schematron

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon, schematron

I am trying to compile Schematron file through the XSLT file (iso_svrl_for_xslt2.xsl) with help of Saxon9HE as described [here](http://www.schematron.com/implementation.html) and [there](http://blog.eight02.com/2011/05/validating-xml-with-iso-schematron-on.html).

Here I am calling Saxon with 3 arguments:

**-o:schema-compiled.xsl** is the output file (XSLT script)

**-s:example_schematron.xsl** is the source file

**iso-schematron-xslt2/iso_svrl_for_xslt2.xsl** is the stylesheet file, used to compile schematron file into XSLT script

```
java -jar saxon9he.jar -o:schema-compiled.xsl -s:example_schematron.sch iso-schematron-xslt2/iso_svrl_for_xslt2.xsl
```

Here are the files:

example_schematron.sch:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.ascc.net/xml/schematron">
  <title>Test Schematron</title>
  <pattern name="My rules">
      <rule context="User">
            <assert test="count(email) != 1">
                  User shall have exactly one email
            </assert>
      </rule>
</pattern>
</schema>
```

schema-compiled.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

Why am I getting empty schema-compiled.xsl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't looked at the stylesheet but I think (based on http://www.schematron.com/iso/iso-schematron.rnc.txt and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schematron#Versions) that the ISO Schematron language defines its elements in the namespace `http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron` while your file uses a different namespace. So perhaps you need to adapt your schema to use the ISO namespace or you need to use a different stylesheet for your schema than the ISO stylesheet.

Comment: Thank you a lot! It finally worked. You are right, the namespace in my file is obsolete as it says here [link](http://www.schematron.com/resources.html). But I read it wrong and thought that it's the other way around:  `http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron` had to be changed to `http://www.ascc.net/xml/schematron`. Silly me.